# Intent es null en el onRecieve() de un BroadcastReciver

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo un problema que no consigo entender porque ocurre, he estado buscando por más sitios antes de preguntar pero no he encontrado nada, aquí va el problema:

Yo creo un Intent para enviar un broadcast de la siguiente manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(contexto,BroadcastReciver.class);
intent.putExtra("key","texto"));
contexto.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Esto hace que la clase BroadcastReciver se inicie y entre en el método `onRecive()` y hago lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String aux=intent.getStringExtra("key");
}
```

Pues cuando llega ahí, ese Intent que recivo tiene los Extras a null y no se porque, he verificado que a la hora de crear el intent los datos no vayan vacíos y esta todo correcto hasta llegar a la clase del BroadcastReciver.

**EDITADO:**
En manifest.xml lo tengo declarado de la siguiente manera:

```
 <receiver android:name=".utils.BroadcastReciver" />
```

utils es un paquete tengo creado yo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido hacerlo de una forma un poco "chapucera" y que a mi parecer no es una solución.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(contexto,BroadcastReciver.class);
intent.setAction("texto");
contexto.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Y en el onReceive():

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String aux= intent.getAction();
}
```

De esta manera, pasando el String como una acción  puedo obtenerlo después y usarlo para mi propósito.

El problema de esto es que se estaría utilizando un método `intent.setAction()` que su función no es la que le estoy dando, y otro problema sería que solamente se le podría pasar un dato tipo String.

Por eso digo que es una "chapuza" y no una solución, pero bueno, de momento me funciona y me deja continuar con mi desarrollo.

Comment: prueba dejarle el set action ,creo que es necesario aunque no lo uses y usa el put extra

Comment: Ya lo intenté y nada, sigue teniendo los extras a null